# Does thermodynamics deal with nuclear rections?

Tags: thermodynamics

Recently read about nuclear reactors and noticed that the interpreted physics behind the process does not mention the correlation of transmutation and thermodynamic potentials.
Engergy generated by radioactive decay released (inflicted?) by mass change. It means that the degree of freedom for the system changes value. Does it have some contradiction?

Comment: This question is asked in too obscure way; I don't understand what you are asking and therefore cannot answer. If it is the change in the number of nuclei that bothers you, then that is not particularly different from the change in the numbers of molecules in chemical reactions. It is accounted for through the thermodynamic potential called chemical potential.

Answer (score 1):

Atoms involved in a fission reaction decompose from unstable, higher energy atoms to more stable, lower energy atoms; energy is released.

In fusion. atoms combine from high energy less stable atoms to larger, more stable, lower energy atoms. Energy is released

High potential energy systems changing to lowere potential energy systems will always release energy in the form of mass, light, heat, etc. Basic thermodynamics.

Answer (score 0):

The transmutation of elements in a fission reactor always obeys the first law of thermodynamics: mass/energy can neither be created nor destroyed. Radioactivity is usually a fairly long winded process which generates comparatively little energy, so rather than wait for the uranium to decay, the reactor induces it to fission, which is a much more energetic process. Fusion reactors haven't been perfected yet; the longest fusion reaction achieved so far lasted about a second, and consumed far more energy than it produced. An economically useful fusion reactor is still about 20 years away, perhaps longer, but fission or fusion, they both have to obey the first law of thermodynamics.

Comment: I studied metallurgy, I know that thermodynamics works. Just wondered about its appliance for fusion/fission.